# How to use SQLab Xpert Tuning to tune SQL for better performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Anyone have any idea? And any open source sofware which also seens to perform this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking, it is pretty straightforward, you type in your SQL and SQLLab Xpert tries many combinations of rewriting your query and runs them all, selecting the fastest. I find the approach a little dubious, you probably will get something that runs faster than what you originally had, but probably not the fastest possible (unless it is very simple SQL).
I prefer to hand tune, the Oracle performance manual http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/toc.htm, Chapters 11-20, has all the information you need, in my opinion better than the shotgun approach SQLLab Xpert takes.